# Two user requests modify the same datastore entity in Google App Engine Application?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it a good practice? One user makes request and gets entity from datastore, changes it and saves. Another user does this simultaneously with the same entity. Will second user see first user's changes if first user's request isn't yet completed? What pattern should I use if I want two users to make "agreement"? First says "yes", than second says "yes", than the deal is done. Do i have to use polling from client-side to monitor it?

Comment: This is where transactions are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need transactions for that.

Read here for more info and practices : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview

Transactions happen with the logic that the first that commits wins! 
But retries are possible...

```
@db.transactional(retries=3)
def make_agreement_for_user_a(agreement):
    agreement = Agreement.get(agreement)
    if agreement.user_a:
        return "User A has already agreed"
    agreement.user_a = TRUE
    agreement.put()
    if agreement.user_b:
        return "Agreement complete"
    return "User A agreed"

@db.transactional(retries=3)
def make_agreement_for_user_b(agreement):
    agreement = Agreement.get(agreement)
    if agreement.user_b:
        return "User B has already agreed"
    agreement.user_b = TRUE
    agreement.put()
    if agreement.user_a:
        return "Agreement complete"
    return "User B agreed"
```

It's just an example and it's not optimized neither check if there is already an agreement.
The rest is up to you